# How works CSS grid-autoflow?

Tags: css, css-grid

I faced with the problem that I don't understand how implicit grids work. I read the documentation, MDN and a couple of resources more. But there is an open question.

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template: repeat(2, 100px) / repeat(6, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 1rem;
  font-size: 2rem;
}

.grid__item {
  background-color: #BDBDBD;
}

.grid__item--1 {
  grid-row: 1 / -1;
}

.grid__item--5 {
  grid-row: 1 / -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="grid__item grid__item--1">1</div>
  <div class="grid__item grid__item--2">2</div>
  <div class="grid__item grid__item--3">3</div>
  <div class="grid__item grid__item--4">4</div>
  <div class="grid__item grid__item--5">5</div>
  <div class="grid__item grid__item--6">6</div>
</div>
```

And here is the result:
[image: example]

**Why does the fifth block go before the second?**

**Code**: https://jsfiddle.net/serhioses/51do02xa/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is defined [in this part of  the specification](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-grid/#auto-placement-algo) where we first have:

> 2. Process the items locked to a given row.
>
> For each grid item with a definite row position (that is, the `grid-row-start` **and** `grid-row-end` properties define a definite grid position), in order-modified document order:

then

> 4. Position the remaining grid items.

So basically we position the items that have an explict placement inside rows (both `grid-row-start` AND `grid-row-end` should be different from `auto`) then we place the other considering the algorithm described in the above specification.

Even if you modify the order you will have the same result:

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template: repeat(2, 100px) / repeat(6, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 1rem;
  font-size: 2rem;
}

.grid__item {
  background-color: #BDBDBD;
}

.grid__item--1 {
  grid-row: 1 / -1;
}

.grid__item--5 {
  grid-row: 1 / -1;
  order:100;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="grid__item grid__item--1">1</div>
  <div class="grid__item grid__item--2">2</div>
  <div class="grid__item grid__item--3">3</div>
  <div class="grid__item grid__item--4">4</div>
  <div class="grid__item grid__item--5">5</div>
  <div class="grid__item grid__item--6">6</div>
</div>
```

Comment: If I change `1 / -1` to `span 2` an item becomes implicitly positioned. Am I right?

Comment: @СергейМирошник yes because the grid-row-end will be auto and no more explicit ... both start and end need to be explicit

Comment: @СергейМирошник `span 2` mean `grid-row-start:span 2` and `grid-row-end:auto`

Comment: Thank you! So helpful for me.